# Multi Dimensional Array Construct

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this type of array that I got from my SQL result.

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| business_id | business_name | business_branch | branch_contact |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      1      |      ABC      |        1        |   1111111111   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      1      |      ABC      |        2        |   2222222222   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      1      |      ABC      |        3        |   3333333333   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      1      |      ABC      |        4        |   4444444444   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      2      |      XYZ      |        1        |   5555555555   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      2      |      XYZ      |        2        |   6666666666   |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

At the beginning I thought of doing a separate database query for each branches and businesses. But got to know it was a bad practice.

I want to construct the results as following

```
[
{
  business_id : 1,
  business_name : ABC,
  branches : [
  {
    branch_id : 1,
    branch_contact : 1111111111
  },
  {
    branch_id : 2,
    branch_contact : 2222222222
   },
   ...
 },
 {
   business_id : 1,
   business_name : ABC,
   branches : [
   {
      ...
   }
 }
]
}
```

The current function I'm trying to build doesn't give the necessary output. It is shown below.

```
$previousBusiness = '';
$previousBranch = '';
$businessAndBranchArray = [];
$businessArray = [];
$branchArray = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $currentBranch = [];
    $currentBusiness = [];
    $currentMerchant = [];

    if($result['business_id'] != $previousBusiness && $result['branch_id'] != $previousBranch){

        if($previousBranch != '' && $previousBusiness != ''){

            $businessArray['business_id'] = $result['business_id']; 
            $businessArray['business_id'] = $result['business_name'];

            $branchArray['branch_id'] = $result['branch_id'];
            $branchArray['branch_contact'] = $result['branch_contact'];

        } else {

            $businessArray['business_id'] = $result['business_id']; 
            $businessArray['business_id'] = $result['business_name'];

            $branchArray['branch_id'] = $result['branch_id'];
            $branchArray['branch_contact'] = $result['branch_contact'];
        }
        $previousBusiness = $result['business_id']; 

    } else {
        $branchArray['branch_id'] = $result['branch_id'];
        $branchArray['branch_contact'] = $result['branch_contact'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to keep track of previous items and such, just use the ID as an array key so you can check it exists. If you don't want it in your final output, use `array_values()` to remove the keys:

```
<?php
$results = [
    ["business_id" => 1, "business_name" => "ABC", "business_branch" => 1, "branch_contact" => "1111111111"],
    ["business_id" => 1, "business_name" => "ABC", "business_branch" => 2, "branch_contact" => "2222222222"],
    ["business_id" => 1, "business_name" => "ABC", "business_branch" => 3, "branch_contact" => "3333333333"],
    ["business_id" => 1, "business_name" => "ABC", "business_branch" => 4, "branch_contact" => "4444444444"],
    ["business_id" => 2, "business_name" => "XYZ", "business_branch" => 1, "branch_contact" => "5555555555"],
    ["business_id" => 2, "business_name" => "XYZ", "business_branch" => 2, "branch_contact" => "6666666666"],
];
$output = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (empty($output[$result["business_id"]])) {
        $output[$result["business_id"]] = [
            "business_id" => $result["business_id"],
            "business_name" => $result["business_name"],
            "branches" => [],
        ];
    }
    $output[$result["business_id"]]["branches"][] = [
        "branch_id" => $result["business_branch"],
        "branch_contact" => $result["branch_contact"],
    ];
}

echo json_encode(array_values($output), true);
```

Output:

```
[{"business_id":1,"business_name":"ABC","branches":[{"branch_id":1,"branch_contact":"1111111111"},{"branch_id":2,"branch_contact":"2222222222"},{"branch_id":3,"branch_contact":"3333333333"},{"branch_id":4,"branch_contact":"4444444444"}]},{"business_id":2,"business_name":"XYZ","branches":[{"branch_id":1,"branch_contact":"5555555555"},{"branch_id":2,"branch_contact":"6666666666"}]}]
```

Comment: working like a charm. Thanks for the help :)
can I know what is the best practice. The above approach of mine or key-value appraoch (when considering building REST API)